# Use the rule for differentiating a product to prove that the derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$ for all $n∈N$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, induction

I know the rule of differentiation, but to proving why the derivative is that is my problem. Should I be proving this question by induction because that's what I've been learning.

Comment: Directly from the definition $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^n - x^n}{h}$ and using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to the term $(x+h)^n$ is another option. Induction is technically easier though.

Answer (score 3):

Yep! The base case should be immediate. For the inductive step, we can break off an $x$ and use Product Rule in order to apply the induction hypothesis:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ x^n \right] = \frac{d}{dx} \left[ x \cdot x^{n - 1} \right] = x \cdot \underbrace{\frac{d}{dx} \left[ x^{n - 1} \right]}_{
\begin{array}{c}\text{apply ind.} \\ \text{hyp. here}\end{array}} + \frac{d}{dx} \left[ x \right] \cdot x^{n-1} = \cdots
$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get it.

Comment: @nyorkr23 $$\cdots=x\cdot(n-1)x^{n-2}+1\cdot x^{n-1}=(n-1)x^{n-1}+x^{n-1}=nx^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the product differentiation rule for  product of $n$ functions, you don't need induction. Simply, $\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^n) = \dfrac{d}{dx}(x\cdot x\cdot ...\cdot x) = x^{n-1}+x^{n-1}+...+x^{n-1}=nx^{n-1}.$